# Is it possible to open a browser window from a aservice worker?

Tags: service-worker

I would like to open a new browser window from inside a service worker, depending on the information in the http request that the service worker has intercepted, for example:

```
// inside service worker:

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  if (event.request.url.indexOf('trigger=') > -1) {

    // OPEN A NEW BROWSER WINDOW...

    event.respondWith(
      new Response(JSON.stringify({ triggered: event.request.url }), {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      }),
    )
  } else {
    event.respondWith(
      fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response
      }),
    )
  }
})
```

From what I have read, it seems that the only way to do this, is to click on a notification that is displayed as a result of having received a push message.  That is to, you register a "notification click event" listener, which will allow you to pop open a new window?  [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow) for more info.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this without the need for any sort of push notification?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it's fairly simple actually:

```
// inside service worker:

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', e => {
  e.notification.close()
  clients.openWindow('http://localhost/')
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  if (event.request.url.indexOf('trigger=') > -1) {

    self.registration.showNotification('Click here to open the app')

    event.respondWith(
      new Response(JSON.stringify({ triggered: event.request.url }), {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      }),
    )
  } else {
    event.respondWith(
      fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response
      }),
    )
  }
})
```

You need to request permission to display notifications when registering the service worker of course, but otherwise it works.